# Creating a partial view using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, nopcommerce

I have got a masterpage which uses a model @model.topics, I created a partial view which uses a model @model.ContactUsModel, And i am rendering that view in my master page , but it comes up with the error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Nop.Web.Models.Common.topics', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Nop.Web.Models.ContactUsModel'.

I am calling the partial view using :

```
 @Html.Partial("Contact")
```

Any suggestions or advice what i am doing wrong here

Comment: How are you calling the partial view?

Comment: @Html.Partial("Contact")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
@Html.Action("Contact")
```

The action has to return a `PartialView` for this to work. You can then render it with the right model

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
   blabla, some code
   return PartialView(myContactUsModelObject);
}
```

`@Html.Partial()` renders the partial view.
It **doesn't** invoke the action in the **controller**.
You can still give a model with this method like this: `@Html.Partial("Contact",someObject)`
If you don't give a model with it, the page model will be given by default
and that is what happend with your code

`@Html.Action()` invokes the action in the **controller**.
And then it is up to the action to give a result of any kind.

I hope this helps

Comment: A public action method 'Contact' was not found on controller 'Nop.Web.Controllers.TopicController'.

Comment: although i have got a controller there

Comment: @MrA: Sure you are in the right conrtoller then?
Could be that you need to specify it @Html.Action("Contact","Controller");

Comment: sorted out cheers mate , just need to know why we use action instead of partial

Comment: so u mean html.partial views doesnt required action methods to render ui

Answer (score 2):

Partial just render the View. The Action calls the Controller and it render the View. So if your view need any code provided by the Controller (like ViewBag) you need to call Action(). Otherwise call View().